# Mobile iPhone Input Form Focus

Tags: iphone, mobile

On Mobile iPhone when I click on a input form it gives me the keyboard with up/down arrows to scroll through the form. Once this happens I can jump around the form focusing anywhere, however when a particular select dropdown is chosen it always focuses back to the first form element. This happens on both Safari and Chrome.

Does anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with a label, duh. I had a "for" tag pointing to the wrong element.

Problem solved!